# wp e-commerce paypal credit cards direct paymanets country error

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, e-commerce

I have a **wordpress** website with **wp e-commerce** installed, i need to activate the paypal pro payment gateway to have direct credit cards payments in my e-commerce, all looks nice, i've put api signatures username and password, activated it and tested it, but when i try to pay it gives me the following error -> "The merchant country is not supported." 
i have an italian paypal account (pro account- buisness)
Any suggestion on why this error comes up ?
Thanks all
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

The error suggest that Paypal Payment Pro service is not available for your country, currently it supports US, UK, Canada only as per [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/howto_product_matrix/).

Comment: i got it, is there any way i can include a direct payment with an italian paypal account ? or do i have to use chronopay or something like athorize.net ?

Answer (score 0):

Only the 'hosted solution' is available in Italy at this time. Direct credit card processing via the `DoDirectPayment` API is unfortunately not available in Italy.